# Create function in R to apply to multiple datasets

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have this code, recommended from a Stackoverflow user that works very well. I have
several datasets that I wish to apply this code to.
Would I have to continuously apply each dataset to the code, or is there something else that I can do? (Like store it in some sort of function?)

I have datsets

```
df1, df2, df3, df4. I do not wish to rbind these datasets.
```

Dput for each dataset:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(1:6, .Label = c("1/2/2020 5:00:00 PM", 
"1/2/2020 5:30:01 PM", "1/2/2020 6:00:00 PM", "1/5/2020 7:00:01 AM", 
"1/6/2020 8:00:00 AM", "1/6/2020 9:00:00 AM"), class = "factor"), 
Duration = c(20L, 30L, 10L, 5L, 2L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

CODE:

```
df %>%
group_by(Date = as.Date(dmy_hms(Date))) %>% 
summarise(Total_Duration = sum(Duration), Count = n())
```

This is what I have been doing for each:(etc)

```
df1 %>%
group_by(Date = as.Date(dmy_hms(Date))) %>% 
summarise(Total_Duration = sum(Duration), Count = n())


df2 %>%
group_by(Date = as.Date(dmy_hms(Date))) %>% 
summarise(Total_Duration = sum(Duration), Count = n())


df3 %>%
group_by(Date = as.Date(dmy_hms(Date))) %>% 
summarise(Total_Duration = sum(Duration), Count = n())
```

Is there a way to:

```
 Store_code<-
 df %>%
 group_by(Date = as.Date(dmy_hms(Date))) %>% 
 summarise(Total_Duration = sum(Duration), Count = n())
```

and then apply each dataset easily to this code?

```
df1(Store_code)
df2(Store_code)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return all the objects into a `list`, use `map` to loop over the `list` and apply the function

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)
f1 <- function(dat) {
      dat %>%
        group_by(Date = as.Date(dmy_hms(Date))) %>% 
         summarise(Total_Duration = sum(Duration), Count = n())
      }

lst1 <- map(mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$")), f1)
```

---

Here, we assume the column names are the same i.e. 'Date', 'Duration' in all the datasets.  If it is a different one, then can pass as another argument to function

```
f2 <- function(dat, datecol, durationcol) {
      dat %>%
        group_by(Date = as.Date(dmy_hms({{datecol}}))) %>% 
         summarise(Total_Duration = sum({{durationcol}}), Count = n())
      }
```

and apply the function as

```
f2(df1, Date, Duration)
```

Or in the loop

```
lst1 <- map(mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+$")), f2, 
         datecol = Date, durationcol = Duration)
```

Comment: Thank you! so essentially, in my case, the list would be:  map(mget(ls(pattern = "df1,df2,df3") ), f1)  ??

Comment: @TanishaHudson `pattern = '^df\\d+$'` or  `mget(paste0('df', 1:3))`

Comment: Ok exactly this? I will try

Comment: Hello Akrun, I believe this is successful, I am just not sure now how to actually view the dataset to see if it worked?

Comment: Should I View(f1)?

Comment: Ok I see it! this works thank you! I viewed the list.  View(lst1)